# Connecting Mysql database with VirtualBox Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, mysql-workbench

I installed Ubuntu on Virtual-box with Vagrant, and Virtual Machine is running on Windows. I'm running my application on Ubuntu through vagrant.

Now I want database for my application, and trying to connect MySQL Workbench with  SSH Host. But workbench is continuously giving error on Authentication.

When i logged in through virtual-box the login credentials i given worked absolutely fine.

[image]

And on same credential workbench is giving error.

[image]

Now What i did is changed my SSH Hostname : 127.0.0.1:2222 as identified in Bash :

[image]

[image]

Now i'm getting this error.

I'm doing blunders in making connection, but couldn't locate from where i went wrong. Please help me setting up database for my application.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `vagrant up` notice a line like this:

```
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

This means port 22 (SSH port) of guest is mapped to port 2222 on host. So when accessing with normal SSH command you need to access port 2222 on host.

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Change the port to 2222 in SSH hostname and you should be fine.

```
SSH hostname: 127.0.0.1:2222
```

Comment: Sir I have done changes and edited my question as you recommended. I think now error is due to SSH Key file, because before the error given by work bench, it asked me for SSH Key File, i tried to find SSH file in vagrant folder but didn't succeed. Can you please tell me where i will find my SSH Key file.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Check for a file named `insecure_private_key` in `.vagrant.d` folder.

Comment: i am pinging 127.0.0.1:5000, but cmd says Ping request could not find any host, while flask is running on this port. What could be the issue?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar you need to forward port 5000 in `Vagrantfile` and also you need to make sure that flask is listening for all interfaces, i.e. running on `0.0.0.0:5000`.

Comment: can you tell me how to forward port 5000 in vagrant file, actually i'm beginner and need help for setting up my database. I have posted question related to my issue, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321679/windows-cmd-not-detecting-flask-server