# Windows cmd not detecting flask server

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, mysql-workbench, vagrant-windows

I'm working on vagrant and running host on 127.0.0.1:5000, but problem is cmd is not detecting any host, due which workbench is continuously giving error on making ssh connection.

Here is my host running :

[image]

And flask server is running on port :5000

[image]

And workbench is countinously giving error. I think error is due to workbench is unable to locate host :

[image]

In vagrant file forwarded_port is 5000 :

[image]

Comment: why do you ping 127.0.0.1:2222 ? first you missed the `:` second ping only works on port 80 and finally 2222 has been enabled for ssh connection - flask is running on port 5000, if you curl 127.0.0.1:5000 (as you forward port) it will reply - then for mysql connection look [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34016049/4296747)

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't even notice about that(:), and i will go through your answer.

Comment: @Frederic My forwarded port is 5000 as i updated my question, but still i'm getting error. What could be the problem?

Comment: if you do `curl 127.0.0.1:5000` from the VM it works ? from the host it does not work ? then might be a firewall issue from the VM or the host